# Error: Spinner(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

[image]

I am new to react. I was trying to add Spinner in my app, and I got this error.
Error: Spinner(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Thanks in advance

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profile";

const Dashboard = ({
  getCurrentProfile,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
  }, [getCurrentProfile]);

  return loading && profile === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Dashboard</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user' />
        Welcome {user && user.name}
      </p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  profile: state.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentProfile })(Dashboard);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Spinner.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import spinner from "./spinner.gif";

const Spinner = () => {
  <Fragment>
    <img
      src={spinner}
      style={{ width: "200px", margin: "auto", display: "block" }}
      alt='Loading..'
    />
  </Fragment>;
};

export default Spinner;
```

Comment: Read [the section on implicit returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). That's what you seem to be expecting to happen, but are missing the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Spinner.js` file you need to return the Spinner component

e.g.

```
const Spinner = () => {
  return (
   <Fragment>
     <img
       src={spinner}
       style={{ width: "200px", margin: "auto", display: "block" }}
       alt='Loading..'
     />
   </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bringing the loading && profile == NULL statment inside the return statement.

```
return ( loading && profile === null ? 
<Spinner /> :
<Fragment>
  <h1 className='large text-primary'>Dashboard</h1>
  <p className='lead'>
    <i className='fas fa-user' />
    Welcome {user && user.name}
  </p>
</Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spinner.js, the brackets around the method mean that the content is not returned. Either remove them or add a return statement to return the fragment.

Eg :

```
const Spinner = () => {
  return (
   <Fragment>
     <img
       src={spinner}
       style={{ width: "200px", margin: "auto", display: "block" }}
       alt='Loading..'
     />
   </Fragment>
  );
};
```

OR

```
const Spinner = () => 
   <Fragment>
     <img
       src={spinner}
       style={{ width: "200px", margin: "auto", display: "block" }}
       alt='Loading..'
     />
   </Fragment>
  );
```